# Is there any reason to FTP files in ASCII and not use binary by default?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, ftp, binary, ascii

I FTP a lot of files with accents in the filenames.

When I use Transmit to transfer them in ASCII mode, the accents are not transferred correctly.

When I transfer them in binary mode, the accents are fine.

**This made me think: what's the benefit of using ASCII for FTP transfers?**

**Is there any reason not to use binary mode all the time?**

Comment: Convert CR+LF to LF or the other way around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the benefit of using ASCII for FTP transfers?

If you are transferring non-ASCII data, there is no benefit in using ASCII mode.  (In fact, it is harmful.)

> Is there any reason not to use binary mode all the time?

Well, if you *are* sending simple ASCII text files, especially between platforms with different end-of-line sequences, then sending in ASCII mode will convert end-of-lines to the form appropriate to the system you are transferring the file to.  (So that, for example, the files won't cause the Windows "Notepad" utility to stuff up.)

> So why do (some) FTP clients assume ASCII by default?

Because the FTP specification ([RFC 959 Section 3.1.1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/3_DataTransfer.html)) states that ASCII is the default type for transfers.

> Why is it that way?

For historical reasons.  According to the RFC, the FTP protocol had its origins in 1971, years before the Internet existed.  In those days, most files a user would want to transfer over the network *would have been* ASCII.  (OK ... I'm guessing.)

> Why don't they change it?

Because changing the spec would unnecessarily break legacy applications and use-cases implemented against the current and earlier versions of the FTP specification.)

Comment: I'd say that most modern GUI FTP clients default to binary these days. Though obviously the long-existing command-line FTP clients have to stick to their legacy defaults, because changing it would break existing scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of the EOL aspect. Since I am always working on Unix (Mac) and uploading to Apache, I will just use binary all the time. I had an idea that binary might be three times slower for some reason.